# Tensorflow - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow, please help to fix this error. I used the Tensorflow Tutorial code to convert the pandas dataframe inputs to tensors using get_input_fn, but i am stuck with this error. Little help would be grateful.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8ac4f79a2981> in <module>()
114 
115 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 116     main()

<ipython-input-4-8ac4f79a2981> in main()
105     Xtrain = pd.concat([Xtrain, ytrain], axis = 1)
106     Xtest = pd.concat([Xtest, ytest], axis = 1)
--> 107     Tensors(Xtrain, Xtest)

<ipython-input-4-8ac4f79a2981> in Tensors(Xtrain, Xtest)
 30     print(feature_cols)
 31     nnreg = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns = 
feature_cols, hidden_units = [10, 10])
 ---> 32     nnreg.fit(input_fn = get_input_fn(Xtrain), steps = 5000)
 33     ev = nnreg.evaluate(input_fn = get_input_fn(Xtest, num_epochs = 1, shuffle = False))
 34     loss_score = ev['loss']

<ipython-input-4-8ac4f79a2981> in get_input_fn(data, num_epochs, shuffle)
 22                     y = tf.constant(data[label].values),
 23                     num_epochs = num_epochs,
---> 24                     shuffle = shuffle)
 25 
 26 def Tensors(Xtrain, Xtest):

C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\pandas_io.py in pandas_input_fn(x, y, batch_size, num_epochs, shuffle, queue_capacity, num_threads, target_column)
 83           'Cannot use name %s for target column: DataFrame already has a '
 84           'column with that name: %s' % (target_column, x.columns))
 ---> 85     if not np.array_equal(x.index, y.index):
 86       raise ValueError('Index for x and y are mismatched.\nIndex for x: %s\n'
 87                        'Index for y: %s\n' % (x.index, y.index))

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'
```

This is my get_input_fn() for pandas dataframe.

```
def get_input_fn(data, num_epochs = None, shuffle = True):
        features = ['name', 'ship', 'GC', 'SC1_Enc', 'SC2_Enc', 'rating', 'condition', 'pol']
        label = ['target']
        return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
                x = {k: tf.constant(data[k].values) for k in features},
                y = tf.constant(data[label].values),
                num_epochs = num_epochs,
                shuffle = shuffle)
```

Comment: there is no index attribute on either x or y.  Did you mean to do x['index'] or y['index']?  Hard to offer any help without knowing what x or y is.

Comment: X's features name, ship, GC, SC1_Enc, SC2_Enc are categories which i encoded using cat.codes while rating, condition, pol are numerical variables, y is the target price which has to be predicted.                       name  ship  GC  SC1_Enc  SC2_Enc  rating  condition   pol  target                         926224  0     10  104           762            2.081545      2      0.15  9.0

Comment: above is one row of the dataframe Xtrain.

Comment: @user2263572 I cahnged my x in get_input_fn to this x = tf.constant(data[features].values), the above error didn't throw up but ti got this new error now **AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'copy' **   C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\inputs\pandas_io.py in pandas_input_fn(x, y, batch_size, num_epochs, shuffle, queue_capacity, num_threads, target_column)
     77                     'got {}'.format(shuffle))
     78 
---> 79   x = x.copy()
     80   if y is not None:
     81     if target_column in x:

Comment: In python dictionaries have a copy attribute.  Make sure you aren't calling copy on a different data type.